# Why are the elements inside "array" changed when I never directly modify it?

Tags: c#, arrays

The following code changes the elements in the `array` variable. I would expect changes in `sortedArray` but it make changes in both. I never have `array` on the left hand side of any equals sign. I'm never setting `array` to any value, yet I see changes in it in the debugger when I watch.

```
static int[] SortArray(int[] array)
{
    int[] sortedArray = array;

    while (!IsSorted(sortedArray))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if( sortedArray[i] > sortedArray[i + 1])
            {
                sortedArray[i] = array[i + 1];
                sortedArray[i + 1] = array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return sortedArray;
}
```

Before the `SortArray` method is called, `array` is (8, 3, 1, 6, 4), and when the method is done, `array` is (1, 1, 1, 4, 4).

Comment: It's time to learn about _reference types_.

Comment: Here is a smaller [mre] of your problem. https://dotnetfiddle.net/a6xoQL

Comment: Thank you for your two links. I will use the procedure for minimal reproducible examples, next time I have a problem.
Can bug you for a clarification?
So arrays are reference types and therefore making an array variable (B) and assigning it to an array (A), does not create two separate arrays (in memory), but just one array that are references by two differently named reference types?
That's why the new keyword is needed when making an array, because we need to create an instance of it, since it's a reference type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the statement `int[] sortedArray = array;`. With this statement, you're assigning `array` to `sortedArray`. Both variables now point to the same array in memory so any change made to it via one of them will also be visible via the other one (since they both point to the same array!).

It seems you meant to copy the array. You could do this by using [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-7.0), or even manually:

```cs
int[] sortedArray = new int[array.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
{
    sortedArray[i] = array[i];
}
```